# Jquery cookie plugin s

Tags: javascript

Как заcookieть этот код?

```
$(".sort__View").on("click","a",function() {
    var sort = $(this).data("sort");
    $(".sort__View a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $(".items__Sort").fadeOut(0);
    $("."+sort).fadeIn(0);
    return false;
});
```

Тобишь что бы при перезагрузке данные считывались из куков?

Comment: Не очень понятно что значит закукить код? вы хотите сохранить js код в куки или данные? Можно сохранить код в виде строки в localstorage или cookie и выполнить с помощью eval, но это не очень хорошее решение.

Answer (score 1):

Вот то что ты хочешь, только с использованием не кук, а локального хранилища:

```js
$(".sort__View").on("click", "a", function() {
  var sort = $(this).data("sort");

  localStorage.setItem('sort__View', sort);

  $(".sort__View a").removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");
  $(".items__Sort").fadeOut(0);
  $("." + sort).fadeIn(0);
  return false;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var sort = localStorage.getItem('sort__View');
  if (sort)
    $(".sort__View").data('sort', sort).click();
});
```